# AppIcon is not displaying on SignIn with Apple login pop-up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-cognito, apple-sign-in

This application is for iPhone only. This project is in flutter and AWS Cognito is used for social login. [check this documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social_signin_web_ui/q/platform/flutter/#prerequisites)

AppIcon is not displaying in the apple login pop-up and also in the settings-> Password & Security -> Apps Using AppleID -> AppName. PFA SS for the same.

[image: Apple login pop-up]

[image: Settings]

added xcode appIcon SS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are providing a corresponding icon in your Assets for AppIcon:

[image]

Comment: please check the Xcode AppIcon asset SS in the above question.